# Error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object with \DateTime

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, doctrine-orm, formbuilder

I have one problem with my Symfony project. I have one entity with many \DateTime like this :

```
/**
* @var \DateTime
*
* @ORM\Column(name="date_debut", type="datetime", length=255)
*/
protected $dteDebut ;

function getDteDebut() {return $this->dteDebut;}

function setDteDebut(\DateTime $dteDebut) {$this->dteDebut = $dteDebut;}
```

I use formBuilder with datetime like this:

```
$builder->add('dteDebut', 'datetime', array(
            'label' => 'Date de début :',
            'date_widget' => 'single_text',
            'time_widget' =>'single_text'
        ));
```

And one simple fonction to use my form:

public function organiserAction() {

```
    $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $orga = new \CCF\CCFBundle\Entity\Organiser;
    $form = $this->createForm(new \CCF\CCFBundle\Form\OrganiserForm(), $orga);
    $request = $this->get('request');

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->bind($request);
        var_dump($form->get('dteDebut')->getData());
        if ($form->isValid()) {                
            $em->persist($orga);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('organiser_homepage'));
        }
    }
    //on passe la méthode createView() à la vue pour qu'elle l'affiche
    return $this->render('CCFBundle:Organiser:create.html.twig',array("form"=>$form->createView(),));
}
```

When I valid the form I have one error

> Error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object

Stack Trace

in vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Types/DateType.php at line 53   -

```
public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
{
    return ($value !== null)
        ? $value->format($platform->getDateFormatString()) : null;
}
/**
```

I do not understand where does this error, can you help me?

Comment: strange problem, bwt in the orm column definition of a datetime type i never specify the length...

Comment: can you show what var_dump($form->get('dteDebut')->getData()) gives you ?

Comment: var_dump return : object(DateTime)[468] public 'date' => string '2015-02-19 01:00:00' (length=19) public 'timezone_type' => int 3 public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)

Comment: and if you dump `$orga` before the persist, does the `dteDebut` field is filled by the one you chose in your form?

Comment: yes $orga take the dteDebut from the form : object(CCF\CCFBundle\Entity\Organiser)[394] private 'id' => null protected 'dteDebut' => object(DateTime)[609] public 'date' => string '2015-02-10 18:59:00' (length=19) public 'timezone_type' => int 3 public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok my bad... I was made a error on one other attribute... I have one attribute with type date and this attribute have a type string in the form...

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
/**
* @var \DateTime
*
* @ORM\Column(name="date_debut", type="datetime", length=255)
*/
protected $dteDebut ;

function getDteDebut() {return $this->dteDebut;}

function setDteDebut(new \DateTime $dteDebut) {$this->dteDebut = $dteDebut;}
```

Comment: With your proposition I have one "Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW), expecting '&' or variable (T_VARIABLE)" error.

Answer (score 0):

I use datetime in one of my entities, too.  One change I see is that I don't specify in the setter that the variable is a datetime object

```
setDteDebut($dteDebut) {...}
```

Comment: I also did testing without specifying the type in the setter but it changes nothing.